# How can I change SearchView to make it works

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I have a working listview with a searchview but when I search something in searchview and click founded item it opens always the first activity, how can I change it to make it work correctly?

```
    SearchView searchView;
    ListView listView;

    String[] nameList = {
            "A", "B1", "B2", "B3"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,nameList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_A.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_B1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_B2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_B3.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Comment: in onItemClick the first result would open "Activity_A", no matter what was typed/found, so maybe open the Activity based on input string or better, some id.

Comment: How can I do this? I'm already started learning this.

Answer (score 0):

use setOnItemSelectedListener instead of setOnItemClickListener

```
SearchView searchView;
ListView listView;

String[] nameList = {
        "A", "B1", "B2", "B3"
};

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,nameList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_A.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_B1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_B2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (position == 3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_B3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {           
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: @DodusiakPL please fix errors if any. I am using this syntax in searchview. or show me the errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you search and I assume only one item matches the search, that item position is now 0, so according to your logic, Activity_A will be started with onClick. So the code is working as it should. So you have to use a different logic to open the right activity, like text inside the list item view.